# Auto Conversion to XML from Java Object is not working in Restlet

Tags: rest, restlet, restlet-2.3.1

I have a method

```
@Get("xml")
public User getUser()
{
 return new User();
}
```

In this case when calling this method browser is showing null as response. I have also annotated the `User` class with `@XmlRootElement` Tag.

It is working fine for Json transformation

```
@Get("json")
public User getUser()
{
 return new User();
}
```

Please help me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the converter service of Restlet for automatic transformation of objects to payload and payload to objects.

I don't know what you use for JSON, but for XML and JAXB you need to add the `org.restlet.ext.jaxb` jar file corresponding to the JAXB extension of Restlet.

Doing that a converter for JAXB will be automatically add into the Restlet engine to actually handle such beans.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I have this jar in my classpath still it is not working for me. I guess it is converting the object to xml but resulting in null value for object

Comment: I just added ObjectFactory Class annotated with `@XMLRegistory` to register User Object and now every thing is working.Still surprised why this is needed

Comment: `package com.rest.xml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public User create() {
        return new User();
    }

}` Added this class in my package